# Django static files in an egg file

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, static-content

I'm want to deploy my django project as an egg file which I am able to. The problem is when serving static files, how do I setup apache (using mod_wsgi) to serve content from an egg file, is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" is it possible ?"  No.

Apache can only serve files.  Simple files.

Or -- for non files -- redirect to some other processing like mod_wsgi.

If you want to serve something packed inside a Python egg (really a Zip archive) you should unpack that member into an ordinary file system location.

Python's `setup.py` has ways to move files from the distribution kit into file system locations.

http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files